# performSelectorInBackground causes memory leaks on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Why does methods that run in the background using performSelectorInBackground create lot of memory leaks?

Thanks.

Comment: How do those memory leaks show. Did you check using instruments?

Answer (score 1):

Create an [NSAutoReleasePool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the start of your called method

`NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];`

and at the end:

`[pool release];`

Check Apple's documentation about [NSAutoReleasePool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s.

Comment: well, i did add  NSAutoReleasePool, but get list of messages like this one: __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1526d0 of class UILayoutContainerView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Comment: Have you added it in the method called using `performSelectorInBackground` (not in the caller)?

Comment: should i add it in performSelectorInBackground? or in the caller?

Comment: In the method called by your `performSelectorInBackground` call.